# How can I compile ONLY resources for Android app?

Tags: android, manifest

I have an unsigned Android application. It`s allready compiled and I need to change app Icon or application name without project compilation. How can I compile only resources or set my often changing params into the RAW dir?

Answer (score 0):

open with Archive Manager and open the res folder the open the drawable folder delete icon.png and drag your icon into that folder.

de-compile your manifest using http://android.amberfog.com/?p=582

and change your app name and replace manifest file in your apk file.

Comment: How can i compile manifest file again after changing? It`s very important - compile ONLY one Manifest.

Comment: Oh i C. can you compile the manifest file with any other project and move the same file to your project? its my idea I dont know  will it work or not?

Comment: No way. I need compile ONE only file - It`s important.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to do this for a legitimate reason? - Sounds a lot like *hacking* someone's App...

Comment: No, It`s my app, but I need compile It "on the fly" and gave it to user but this action need 6-10 seconds and it`s too long for using in real web project.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apktool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/releases).

1. `apktool d <my-package>` to unpack the .apk
2. Modify the resources you need
3. `apktool b -s <my-package>` to rebuild the .apk (`-s` flag skips recompiling the code).
4. Re-sign the .apk (if needed)

Comment: LOL =) Thanks for answer after 5 years from question!